# Disappearing R.class - Android Application Development

Tags: android, performance, android-resources

I'm struggling with disappearing `R.class` due to some problem in `styles.xml` - it says

```
Error retrieving parent for item: 
No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
```

Problem appeared while exporting project to another laptop....

styles.xml below.

Thanks in advance.

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

Comment: I don't know why do you have that issue with "Theme.AppCompat.Light", maybe is because you are forgetting import any compatibility library. Anyway, always that you have an error in whatever file inside of the folder res (resources), the compilation is not going to work and possibly R.class will be not created.

Comment: Follow the instrucctions of Little Child. I am pretty sure too your issue is related with compatibility library that you should include in your project. If it is was helpful, please, score my comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This means you do not have the support library in your build path on your new machine. See the [adding support libraries with resources](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res) section of the docs for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suppose you tried Project -> Clean or to close and re-open eclipse itself. Then you must ensure of adding support libraries as said up.

Answer (score 0):

Lack of R file can be caused by many reasons.
Possible Solutions
Sol 1.  Since it is associated with Theme.AppCompat.Light( which is defined in support library) it may be caused by lack support library in your build path(Appcompat).
Sol 2. Check the version of appcompat and make sure you have the latest one.
Sol 3. Just to be sure. Undo latest changes done in any xml files( or replace the xml file from history).
Sol 4. If you have already added support library and the problem still exists then delete android-support-v4.jar from lib folder if present( this is because conflicting support jar files can cause R file errors).
Sol 5. Check Project Build Target.(Project>Properties>Android)

You can also make sure 'Theme.AppCompat.Light' is present in your support library by placing the cursor between the text(Theme.AppCompat.Light) and press control button which should underline the whole text.

I hope it helped..